# Use two networks to access different resources over internet

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, proxy, bridge

I have the following problem.

In my company, we have a proxy and I can't access some resources that I need for develop so they provide me a external 4g router. Can I bridge the connections so when I can't access a resource via the ethernet then try with the 4g without swapping connections everytime?

**I have:**

*Both connections are in different IPs range.*

- LAN ethernet that goes through corporate proxy and firewall.
- WLAN 4g connection for when I have to access directly or from a external IP to a resource.

**I want:**

> I ask for a resource (URL) -> check via LAN first, and if I can't use LAN to reach it, use WLAN.

*Example (oversimplified):*

- Inner page of the company -> LAN says YES
- External resource that the proxy doesn't allow -> LAN says NO -> 4g says YES

P.D: Our IT says that is a proxy problem but I suspect that the doesn't allow ports for output or something like that...

Thanks for the help! I'm not english native so if you need some aclaration, please, comment it out.

Comment: if you use a proxy config file, you can specify certain sites use a specific proxy, or connect directly.  So you could do something like use a proxy config file to set the problem sites to use a DIRECT connection, otherwise use the proxy, and if your 4G connection is preferred to the corporate proxy (e.g. lower metric than your LAN card), then it would be used, or is it connect-on-demand?

Comment: What I need is to access all the resources via LAN and the proxy in it (corporate) except three or four domains for I have to use the 4G connection (wlan). I don't think that I can change any proxy configuration. So what I though is any configuration for when the LAN fails to access a resource, it uses the wlan connection without swapping the connections manually.

Comment: you could possibly run another proxy on your local machine, and set up your proxy config script to use the corp proxy for all sites except the 4 sites would use the localhost proxy.  This proxy would be configured to use the 4G connection.

Comment: Well, there are several proxies and logic in the corporate pac. Can I redirect to that Pac if the site doesn't not match my local rules?

Comment: the pac contains a jscript function which defines how to connect, so you don't redirect to a pac, you use the pac to redirect to a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You should setup a **proxy.pac**.

### What is a proxy.pac

This is a small Javascript file you can host on your computer. You feed your web browser network configuration with this file and its `FindProxyForURL(url,host)` method will be called to route every URLs your browser need to access.

This Javascript method can use [a set of useful pre-define test functions](http://findproxyforurl.com/pac-functions/) and should return either:

- `"DIRECT"` to bypass proxies and try to connect directly the internet for this URL
- `"PROXY ip:port"` to route to the given proxy (IP/port)
- or several options separated with `"; "` to describe a chain with failover

Such setup makes it very easy to describe comprehensive routing rules based on the URL you are connecting to, or even base on your computer IP address (home/company network) and the weekday (workdays/weekends).

### Example file

[Here is an interesting example](http://findproxyforurl.com/example-pac-file/) for you to see:

```js
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {

// If the hostname matches, send direct.
    if (dnsDomainIs(host, "intranet.domain.com") ||
        shExpMatch(host, "(*.abcdomain.com|abcdomain.com)"))
        return "DIRECT";

// If the protocol or URL matches, send direct.
    if (url.substring(0, 4)=="ftp:" ||
        shExpMatch(url, "http://abcdomain.com/folder/*"))
        return "DIRECT";

// If the requested website is hosted within the internal network, send direct.
    if (isPlainHostName(host) ||
        shExpMatch(host, "*.local") ||
        isInNet(dnsResolve(host), "10.0.0.0", "255.0.0.0") ||
        isInNet(dnsResolve(host), "172.16.0.0",  "255.240.0.0") ||
        isInNet(dnsResolve(host), "192.168.0.0",  "255.255.0.0") ||
        isInNet(dnsResolve(host), "127.0.0.0", "255.255.255.0"))
        return "DIRECT";

// If the IP address of the local machine is within a defined
// subnet, send to a specific proxy.
    if (isInNet(myIpAddress(), "10.10.5.0", "255.255.255.0"))
        return "PROXY 1.2.3.4:8080";

// DEFAULT RULE: All other traffic, use below proxies, in fail-over order.
    return "PROXY 4.5.6.7:8080; PROXY 7.8.9.10:8080";
}
```

Since this is Javascript, you can of course create and use private helper functions and variables.

### Further reading

You will find a bunch of documentation over the Internet. Among others:

- [findproxyforurl](http://findproxyforurl.com) (dedicated website)
- [Cisco support docs](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/web-security-appliance/118076-configure-wsa-00.html)
- [Microsoft technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc985335.aspx)
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config)

### Last tip

I encourage you to only select `FindProxyForURL` result from the host argument, or the URL protocol. Especially, routing several URLs of a single website through different external IPs is not always supported because some website expects a user to have a stable IP address during its entire navigation.

A bunch of load-balancing example have this downside.

Comment: Note: it looks like microsoft added a [host-based result caching](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/271361/how-to-disable-automatic-proxy-caching-in-internet-explorer) which can be seen as a feature or an issue but which should solve the last tip note.